# Can I calculate time between local maxima with featuretools?

Tags: featuretools

I would like to calculate time_since_previous, but not transaction after transaction, instead only between transactions that exceed a maximum value.

Can I do that automatically? or do I need to slice the dataframe?

More specifically, I have a function to detect local maxima, which I do with `scipy.signal.finds_peaks`, which creates a boolean vector with the arrays of the local maxima, which I could add as a feature to the data set, and then I would like the time since previous for those local maxima.

Is that possible in a semi-automated way with featuretools?

If there is a resource doing that, that you could link to this question, that would be great!

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a custom transform primitive can be made then used by DFS to automatically calculate this feature. The `time_since_previous` would only calculate between transactions, so the custom primitive would need to implement the time since the previous local maxima given the boolean vector from `finds_peaks`. Here are guides for defining [simple](https://docs.featuretools.com/en/stable/automated_feature_engineering/primitives.html#defining-custom-primitives) and [advanced](https://docs.featuretools.com/en/stable/guides/advanced_custom_primitives.html#advanced-custom-primitives-guide) custom primitives. Let me know if this helps.